# Why the echo result of $vcs_info_msg_0_ contains strange characters in zsh?

Tags: git, echo, zsh, terminal-color

This is my `PROMPT` configuration in zsh:

```
PROMPT=$'
%{$purple%}%n%{$reset_color%} at %{$orange%}%m%{$reset_color%} in %{$limegreen%}%~%{$reset_color%} $vcs_info_msg_0_
$ '
```

And this is how my zsh displays

[image: shell screenshoot]

At first I just want to get the `master**` string for other use, then I searched for how zsh got it, and found that the message was generated by zsh's `vcs_info` package, and was stored in `$vcs_info_msg_0_`, but as the screenshot shows, the echo result of that variable was very strange. Why did this happen, and how can I just get the git information (`master**` with color) of a repository folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the variable is only to be used in prompts, nowhere else. The strange things you see are special control sequences that are interpreted by ZSH when rendering the prompt.

Comment: Good explanation, so is there any other way to get repo's git information as the prompt shows?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to achieve. All that is being done is just parse the output of `git status`, `git ls-files` etc, so there's nothing that prevents you from doing the same.